# How to end up with a tiny docker image in a multi-stage build?

Tags: docker

I've been operating under the assumption that the benefit of a multi-stage build (and using build_kit) [is a smaller final image](https://www.docker.com/blog/advanced-dockerfiles-faster-builds-and-smaller-images-using-buildkit-and-multistage-builds/).  My experience hasn't shown that.

Consider this:

```
FROM debian:latest AS builder

# Do stuff

FROM alpine:latest AS runner
WORKDIR /

COPY --from=builder /work/myapp.zip .
RUN unzip myapp.zip -d /myapp
```

Then:

```
docker build -t myapp .
docker tag....
docker push ...
```

Then:

```
docker pull our-private-repo/myapp:latest
```

And we are getting back 4 layers with over 600MB of stuff in it combined.  What I think I should be getting is just alpine linux plus our application. It feels like it's pushing everything.  Is it pushing everything?

Comment: What's contained in the zip file? And why copy the zip file rather than the extracted contents? You're doubling the layers by copying and then extracting the zip file.

Answer (score 0):

If your builder can skip zipping the output, then you can copy the output directly `COPY --from=builder /work/myapp` (instead of unzipping), you can get an alpine base with your program only.